Can you run a .bat file from a keyboard macro?
I have a roccat horde aimo keyboard and i would like to map a .bat file execution under a macro button. Is this possible?
Idea is to run the .bat file to backup some files while while running the application.

You can create a file shortcut on your desktop pointing to your bat file, and associate a key combination to run this shortcut (in the properties of the file shortcut).

But i have special macro keys on my keyboard. and will it also work when like a game is open ?
